# Append array of data under one key

Tags: swift

I want to append data to an array. My array needs to look like this:

```
  key -> date 1
              values -> event 1
              values -> event 2
         date 2
              event 1
              event 2
              event 3
```

So I have created this array:

```
var data : [String : [Event]]!
```

But I get the following error when I want to append the data to it:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

That makes sense to me, so I replace the ! with an ?. But then nothing happens at all.

```
var data : [String : [Event]]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var monday : [Event] = []
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "09:00", timeTo: "10:00", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "10:00", timeTo: "11:00", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "13:30", timeTo: "14:30", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "18:30", timeTo: "19:00", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "19:00", timeTo: "20:00", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "19:00", timeTo: "20:00", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "20:00", timeTo: "20:45", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "20:00", timeTo: "21:00", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))
        monday.append(Event(title: "test", timeFrom: "20:00", timeTo: "21:00", maxPlaces: 20, placesFilled: 15))

        data["2018/01/28"]!.append(contentsOf: monday)
    }
```

So my question is, how can I append all the data in monday under key "2018/01/28" for example?

Comment: You should use a simple array literal, instead of appends like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
var data : [String : [Event]]!
```

is a declaration only. It does not actually create the dictionary. And it declares it as implicitly unwrapped.

What you want instead is:

```
var data = [String : [Event]]()
```

This both declares the dictionary and initializes it to an empty dictionary.

Also, at the end of `viewDidLoad`, change:

```
data["2018/01/28"]!.append(contentsOf: monday)
```

to:

```
data["2018/01/28"] = monday
```

Your code will crash because the result of `data["2018/01/28"]` is `nil` and you are then force-unwrapping that `nil`.

If there might actually already be data for the date, then you should do:

```
var array = data["2018/01/28"] ?? []
array.append(contentsOf: monday)
data["2018/01/28"] = array
```

This gets the current array. If there is no current array it creates a new empty array. Then it appends the new values to the array. Then it puts the updates array in the dictionary.

In Swift 4, those three lines can be shortened to:

```
data["2018/01/28", default: []].append(contentsOf: monday)
```

Comment: Before `array.append`, do `data[key] = nil` so that `array`'s buffer remains uniquely referenced, to prevent a CoW

Comment: @Alexander What is "CoW"?

Comment: @rmaddy I would hazard he means Copy On Write.

Comment: @rmaddy You can use Swift 4 Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value to initialize your array with an empty array to be able to append to it even when there is no value yet defined to its key `data["2018/01/28", default: []].append(contentsOf: array)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I always forget about that new feature. Good suggestion.